# Create a Survey in SharePoint 2007 where external users can submit but

Tags: security, sharepoint, moss, survey, extranet

I have a task to make a survey to be displayed in SharePoint 2007 to external users for them to fill out and submit, but not be able to view the submitted results (so they don't see what others have entered).  This survey will be for outside vendors to my company to submit information about them for our records.  I am open to any suggestions on how to accomplish this goal....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished by configuring the survey appropriately. Users will be able to see their own submissions, but not what others have entered:

1. Create a new Survey and populate it with your questions.
2. From the new survey list select **Settings** -> **Survey Settings**
3. Select **Advanced Settings**
4. In the **Item-level Permissions** section set the value of **Read access** and **Edit access** to **Only their own** and click **OK**.

Comment: Thanks dariom!  However while that would normally work, every user to use this survey is a 'Guest,' so if vendor A fills out the survey, that survey will be created by 'Guest' and then if vendor B goes to the survey, they will also be 'Guest'.... is there a way to force some kind of incrementation, like 'Guest001...Guest002'

Comment: Hmmm... It wasn't clear that all your users would be anonymous. You can configure the survey for anonymous users, but I'm not sure how to prevent them from seeing each others' answers (they wouldn't be uniquely identified). I guess you could write a list event receiver to increment the name of the respondent when a new survey item is added, but I haven't tested whether this would meet your requirements.

Comment: There is a commercial web part from Bamboo Solutions that might be useful (I haven't tested it myself). They have a trial version so you could see if it will work for you: http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-poll-web-part.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  I will give that a try and if not, will try the list event receiver option.